# How to plot a function at a particular location (example: inside a rectangle)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two rectangles and I want to plot a function within each.

Is there a way to position a plot? It seems to default to (0,0) and I am not sure how to add a position offset. (to get the red sine wave to be centered within the block B2)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, 
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    blockheight/.style = {
        minimum height=10mm
    },
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        blockheight,
        node distance=5mm,
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    }
]
\node [block] (B1) at (0,0) {};
\node [block, right=10mm of B1] (B2) at (0,0) {};

\draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{sin(180 * \x)});
\draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,red] plot ({\x},{sin(180 * 2*\x)});


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would have put the rectangle and plot together in a scope and shifted the whole scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `shift={(B2.center)}` to the second plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, 
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    blockheight/.style = {
        minimum height=10mm
    },
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        blockheight,
        node distance=5mm,
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    }
]
\node [block] (B1) at (0,0) {};
\node [block, right=10mm of B1] (B2) at (0,0) {};

\draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{sin(180 * \x)});
\draw[shift={(B2.center)},scale=0.4,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,red] plot ({\x},{sin(180 * 2*\x)});


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also work with `path picture` or define a `pic`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/graph/.style={code={%
\draw[thick,top color=white, bottom color=black!10,blur shadow] (-0.6,-0.5) rectangle (0.6,0.5);
#1}}]

 \path pic{graph={\draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{sin(180 * \x)});}}
 (1.5,0) pic{graph={\draw[scale=0.4,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,red] plot ({\x},{sin(180 * 2*\x)});}};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: aha! Thanks, I figured it was easy, wasn't sure how though.

Comment: I'm not even sure you need the `.center`

Comment: @JasonS No, you do not need `.center` here, but I personally find it cleaner.

Comment: Better use Bezier curves.  Plotting the functions each time you want to draw this logo will slow down compilation time considerably.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, *if* it is clear that these are always sine functions, it is advantageous to use the sine path construction. From the question this is, however, not clear. And if you really want a logo that you repeat very often, it is anyway better to use a `savebox` or `xsavebox` or `externalize`.